# How to get data from form and make and array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am just making a railway reservation project to my college therefor I have to get passenger details and make a 2d array and send it to another page to show the summary but I just don't know how to do that.

### my code is

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    session_start();
    $train_number = $_GET['train_number'];
    $train_name = $_GET['train_name'];
    $coachid = $_GET['coachid'];
    $date = $_SESSION['date'];
    $day = $_SESSION['day'];
    $coachtype = $_SESSION['coachtype'];
    $useremail = $_SESSION['useremail'];
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']='POST')
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['proceed']))
        {
            $i = 1;
            while($i<7)
            {
                "What to write here";
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Buy Tickets </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="banner.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard </a></li>
            <li><a href="buytickets.php">Buy Ticket </a></li>
            <li><a href="calcelticket.php">Cancel ticket</a></li>
            <li><a href="edit_profile_user.php">Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li id="last"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?php
            echo "<h4 align='center'><u>Booking for </u></h4>";
            echo "<table align='center'>
              <thead>
              <tr style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>
                <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'> Train Number </th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'> Train name </th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'> Date </th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'> Coach type </th>
              </tr>
              </thead>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$train_number."</td>";
            echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$train_name."</td>";
            echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$date."</td>";
            echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$coachtype."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<h4 align='center'><u>Passenger details </u></h4>";
            echo "<table align='center'>
              <thead>
              <tr style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>
                <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'> No </th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'> Passenger Name </th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'> Age </th>
                <th style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'> Gender type </th>
              </tr>
              </thead>";
            $iforlist = 1;
            while($iforlist<7)
            {
                echo "<form method='post'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$iforlist."</td>";
                echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'><input type='text' name='passenger_name.".$iforlist."' value='' placeholder='Enter name '></td>";
                echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'><input type='number' name='passenger_age.".$iforlist."' value='' max='100' min='1' placeholder='Enter passenger age '></td>";
                echo "<td style='border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left; padding: 8px;'><select name='passenger_gender.".$iforlist."'>
                    <option value='Male'>Male</option>
                    <option value='Female'>Female</option>
                    </select></td></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                $iforlist++;
            }
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<div align='center' style='margin-top:10px;'><input type='submit' align='center' name='proceed' value='Proceed' style='width:100px;height:40px;' placeholder='Enter name '></div>";
            echo "</form>";
        ?>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, tell me how can i make fetch data if only 2 or 3 field are filled and make a 2d array of it.
if you want any other information i'll give you..

Comment: (People automatically vote down posts that mention homework since they think you want them to solve it for you, not saying this is the case). I would take it one step at a time. First, you want to get the passenger details so to do that look up how to parse a webpage. That way you can get the full page data, then from there look up how to filter down the page for what you want (substring, html parser, xml parser, etc). Then how would you store the data (2D array like you mentioned in this case) so look up how to add elements to a 2D array. Remember "Baby Steps" always helps me.

Comment: @Katianie i know how to fetch data from form but i just want to know how can i make an array of it. means can you please give me an example.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I provided and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use 2D Arrays in PHP

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );
```

Now to access the data, you must specify the row and column:

```
<?php
echo $cars[0][0].": In stock: ".$cars[0][1].", sold: ".$cars[0][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[1][0].": In stock: ".$cars[1][1].", sold: ".$cars[1][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[2][0].": In stock: ".$cars[2][1].", sold: ".$cars[2][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[3][0].": In stock: ".$cars[3][1].", sold: ".$cars[3][2].".<br>";
?>
```

In this case:

```
array("Volvo",22,18)
```

That is a single row (0) and it has three columns (Volvo at row=0 column=0, 22 at row=0 colum=1, etc)

I took the example from here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

Let me know if this helps.